# Revive/activate existing panels

Tags: vscode-extensions

My extension have sidebar webview that can create additional webviews as panels in the active text editor. Each of these additional webviews is for an unique item and I want to revive/activate existing webview, for the specific item, if it exists.

My issues:

- I can get a list of the existing tabs with `window.tabGroups.all` and loop through the result. But there is no way, as far as i can see, to reactivate the desired tab. I can get some properties from there but no methods. The question here is: is there a API to get a list of the tabs and be able to revive/activate it?
- Because of the first point ive decided to keep list of the instances of the additional webviews and when new webview is about the be created im checking if its unique id (in the title) is in the list and if it is then just revive the tab instead of creating a new one. Dont like this approach much but its working. The problem here is when the additional webview is closed. When closed it has to be removed from the array. Ive implemented `onDidDispose` for the panel but somehow the filter function, inside it, is not called:

```js
// panels: vscode.WebviewPanel[]

// create new panel
const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel(...)
// add the webview instance to the panel
const newWebview = new AdditionalWebview(panel, this.context);

this.panels.push(panel);

panel.onDidDispose(() => {
   console.log("Before remove the panel"); // can see this in the console
   this.panels = this.panels.filter((p) => p.title != panel.title);
   console.log("Before remove the panel"); // for some reason this never appears
});
```

Not sure why but the panel filter functionality is never triggered (and everything after it is also not ran).

- extra question: at the moment the uniqueness of the additional panels is based on their label/title. In my case thats is ok but is there any other way to get unique identifier of each tab? id/guid somewhere?

Comment: When you say you want to `revive/activate` a tab, do you just mean you want to make it the active editor?  That can be done.  I don't think there is any unique identifier for a tab other than its uri and other characteristics, like `group` for example.  If you want that let us know.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Mark. Yes i want to make it the active tab (to bring it on focus). Regarding the id. its not a big deal if there is none. I can live without it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your first question about activating a given editor, you have a couple of options.

If you know the editor's index/position in its group.  That can be obtained from its `tabGroup.tabs` position - it seems that the tab's index in that array is faithfully its index in the editor.  So you could do a `Array.findIndex` to get the tab uri you want to set to active.

```
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.openEditorAtIndex', [indexToOpen]);

// note the [] around the index argument
```

The only problem with this approach is that it works within the active group **only**, so you may have to activate the correct group **first** via:

```
await vscode.commands.executeCommand('workbench.action.focusSecondEditorGroup');
// or whichever group the tab you want to open is in
```

---

Or second method:

```
// assumes you have the tab

const openOptions = { preserveFocus: true, preview: tab.isPreview, viewColumn: tab.group.viewColumn};
// check if a uri, might be viewtype, etc., instead
if (tab.input instanceof vscode.TabInputText) {
    await vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', tab.input.uri, openOptions);
}
// are your editors regular text editors?
```

This looks like it is opening a new tab but it will focus an existing tab if one exists at that location with that same uri.